# No left click on a Cyborg Rat 7 USB mouse

Tags: mouse

I am having an issue with my usb mouse(cyborg rat 7) I purchased this mouse for the comfort and high dpi, and just made the switch to Ubuntu today, and would really like to stay with this.  But I need the mouse for work.

The problem is that shortly after connecting the mouse I lose left click functions and have to disconnect and reconnect the mouse.  I tried a solution listed in another question by "malisha" -

```
sudo apt-get repository ppa:raof/aubergine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but I got the error "E: invalid operation repository" when I try to enter the first line in the terminal.

Any help with this will be great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong syntax. It should be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:raof/aubergine
```

`apt-get install` is for installing

Add a repo with `add-apt-repository`.